# Optimization when one parameter is more important than other

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am working on an minimization algorithm of the form

\begin{equation}
S = \sum \dfrac{1}{2} r_i^2
\end{equation}

with $r_i = y_i - f(x,\beta)$ is the residual. Here, $f(x,\beta)$ is the Euclidean distance formula:

\begin{equation}
f(x,\beta) = \sqrt{(x_i - \beta_1)^2 + (y_i - \beta_2)^2 + (z_i - \beta_3)^2}
\end{equation}

For such problem, using algorithms like Gauss_newton method, the summation saturates over time and a threshold, $\epsilon$, can be used to terminate the iterative process.

I need to estimate the position coordinates $\{\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3\}$ for this system. This is an unconstrained optimization for now. Let's say, I would like to increase accuracy in the estimation of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, and do not really care about the error in $\beta_3$. Maybe for some reason, it is not possible to predict $\beta_3$ properly by using any measurement since, because of the process physics, it is not possible to know it accurately. How do I build in this requirement in my algorithm?

One way to do it is to constrain $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ such that the estimated parameters are bounded within a certain zone while leaving the unimportant variable to take up any value, thus, making it a constrained optimization problem. But I think there should be another more rigorous way to solve such problems.

Note: I cannot change the $f(x,\beta)$ to not include the $3^{rd}$ dimension since the measurements are in $3$-D space (basically the maths/physics involved in the model does not allow for the unimportant variable to be dropped). A discussion would also help!

Edit: Regarding the accuracy of the system, it has two solutions but if you add constraint e.g. $\beta_i > 0$, then it has just one global minima.

Comment: Perhaps you should state whether $S$ is being minimized or maximized and what the "givens" of your problem are.  You seem to have the $\beta_i$ as the "unconstrained" variables to adjust.   It is unclear what basis for assessing the *accuracy* of estimates is present.  If there is (for example) an exact global minimum of $S$, are you trying to find that minimum accurately?  Or is there some other notion of accuracy?

Comment: @hardmath I added some more info. For such a system, since the optimization process is iterative, you can put a threshold on $S$ obtained from consecutive iterations which stops the iterative process when $S$ saturates.

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to increase accuracy in the estimation"? Usually it goes the other way around, the data has less information regarding one parameter.

Comment: @Royi I think I understand what you mean...To put it in layman terms, for a given set of measurement and model (of the physics/maths that describes the measurement) having multiple parameters to be estimated, can you ensure the estimation of one parameter more accurately than the other? Here the range measurements are described by the euclidean formula for which I have to find of 3 parameters...here $x_i$s are given

Comment: Your threshold on $S$ as a stopping criterion might be supplemented by thresholds on the amount by which $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are adjusted (ignoring when $\beta_3$ may continue to have substantial iterative adjustments).